# CanCan Resource Conditions and special routing with friendly_id slugs

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cancan, rails-routing, friendly-id, update-attributes

I have a Page Model that has a **:name attribute**. I have a specific route for the Page Model with the **name "home"**, because I want this specific Page record to be found at the root_url. This works.. but because I'm hard coding the route... I only want users with the **role "super_admin"** to be able to change the **:name attribute**, on the **Page model**, where the **name == "home"**. For example, users with the **"admin" role** should **not** be able to change the **:name attribute** on the **"home"** Page.

1. Can I get that fine grained with CanCan?
2. Should I put this logic in the **PageControllers** update action?
3. Should I set the **"page#show"** route differently (not hard code it)?

Not sure how to do any of these. 
Thanks in advance for any advice!

**ability.rb**

```
elsif user.role == "admin"
  can :manage, :all
  cannot :update, Page, ["name == ?", "home"] do |page|
    page.name == "home"
  end
end
```

**routes.rb** (I'm using [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) to generate a slug from the **:name attribute**)

```
match '/:slug', :to => "pages#show", :as => :slug, :via => :get
root :to => 'pages', :controllers => "pages", :action => "show", :slug => "home"
```

**pages_controller.rb** (standard)

```
def update
  @page = Page.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @page.update_attributes(params[:page])
      format.html { redirect_to @page, notice: 'Page was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    else
      format.html { render action: "edit" }
      format.json { render json: @page.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must admit, I've read your question three times, and I think I have answers for you...

1 - Yes, I believe so.  However, I'm not convinced your `ability.rb` code is correct.  I'd aim for something closer to this:

```
cannot :update, Page do |page|
  page.name == "home"
end
```

2 - If you do `load_and_authorize_resource` in your controller, that should be all you need, because that will load `@page` for you.

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  load_and_authorize_resource

  def update

    respond_to do |format|
      if @page.update_attributes(params[:page])
        format.html { redirect_to @page, notice: 'Page was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @page.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

end
```

3 - To me, your route looks fine.  That's likely the way I'd approach it.

Comment: thanks for your advice. I had to upgrade to CanCan 2.0 as well.